# SharePoint 2013 standard ribbon not showing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

In my environment I have found that the when using IE 10 I cannot access the list ribbon is some lists. Is this because of an update?

Is there a way to fix this?

Example:

- I have one list where I have 76 items (ribbon works fine)
- I have another list where I have 2576 items (ribbon doesn't work)

I have tried to see if I'm missing the addons. (I'm not)

Could it be list view threshold?

I also get this error "SharePoint library not registered" when I try to debug.

**UPDATE:**

The error started 07 jan 2015, before that everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 10 comes with Compatibility Mode switched off

Try performing following steps:

- Open Internet Explorer 10
- If the Menu bar isn’t visible, click Alt on your Keyboard.
- Click Tools | Compatibility View Settings.
- Select Display all websites in Compatibility View.
- Click Close.

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure that there aren't additional web parts on the list view. If you have more than 1 web part on list view you should firstly click on list area, after then ribbon will appear.